# Found these on my front & back porches, can anyone tell me what they are?

Tags: seeds, bug

These "seeds" don't move, they look just like sesame seeds but black. I woke up this morning and they were all over my back porch. I also found them on the front porch. Never inside unless the dogs bring them in on their paws.
Can someone please tell me if I need an exterminator?

[image: on back porch]

[image: couple in my hand]

Comment: Some plant is dropping black sesame seeds nearby. Do you want to say where you live?